# Is it convention to index a raster band from 1?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, api, naming-conventions

Both GDAL and QGIS's raster calculator index raster bands starting at 1.  This is different than the usual 0 indexed convention that one finds in programming.  And despite Googling, I'm unable to find if band indexing from 1 is a standard convention, or a byproduct of GDAL's convention.  Does anyone know if it is standard convention to refer to a raster's band as 1 based indexing?

For context, I'm developing an API for raster processing and I need to allow the API to express which bands to operate over.  My intuition would be to index them from 0, but I wonder since these industry standard tools do otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it is a definitely a convention that is common and widespread. If you look at the satellite world, you will see the same 1-based numbering in the radiometric bands.

[Landsat bands.](http://landsat.usgs.gov/band_designations_landsat_satellites.php)

[MODIS bands.](http://ocean.stanford.edu/gert/easy/bands.html)

[Sentinel-2 bands.](https://earth.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/resolutions/radiometric)